# Serialize ViewModel, ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have ViewModel with 2 ObservableColection and when my application is closed I serialize my ViewModel.

my code:

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppViewModel.NewsViewModel));
                serializer.Serialize(stream, ViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

AppViewModel.NewsViewModel contains

```
 public ObservableCollection<NewsItemViewModel> EpsItems
            {
                get { return _epsItems; }
            }


            public ObservableCollection<NewsItemViewModel> OthItems
            {
                get { return _othItems; }
            }
```

and the methods by which the filled collections.

NewsItemViewModel:

```
public class NewsItemViewModel
        {
            public NewsItemViewModel()
            {
            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public string FullText { get; set; }
            public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
            public string NewsUrl { get; set; }
        }
```

Everything works fine, but I do not understand how to take, for example, six records take on each collection, and after that serialize ViewModel...How can I do this? For example if EpsItems and OthItems contain 20 entries.

Thanks in advance. And sorry for my bad English ^^

**UPD:** Here is an example where I will describe what I want, but do not know how...
For example: the user has downloaded 30 entries for EpsItems and 25 entries for OthItems, when he closes the application viewmodel serialized. And I keep in storage 30 and 25 entries respectively.  I want to save less entries in collection than user downloads...for example, 10 records of each collection. Question: how do I make this implementation? please help with the implementation and code...

Comment: Can you show a complete example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: why would one serialize the viewmodel? And can you please explain a litte more about what the actual problem is. the explanation on the bottom on you question is misleading for me.

Comment: @MareInfinitus For example, if the user has downloaded 30 entries for EpsItems and 25 entries for OthItems, when he closes the application viewmodel serialized. I need to at this point ViewModel contain, for example, 6 records each collection. the question is "how can I do this; how can I "trimm" collections in viewmodel and only after that serialize it(viewmodel)?!"

Comment: you want to store what the user has already downloaded? why would you not let the model decide that? i.e. why wouldn't you "calculate" the difference in the viewmodel and display that in your view?

Comment: @MareInfinitus NO, just the opposite, I want to store less information than user downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks easy to achieve:

1. Create a method called e.g. `ClearUnnecessaryData` in your `ViewModel` class and do the cleaning there.
2. Call that method before serialization.

Method should look like that:

```
for(int i = MAX_SERIALIZATION_ITEMS; i < EpsItems.Count; )
{
    EpsItems.RemoveAt(MAX_SERIALIZATION_ITEMS);
}

for(int i = MAX_SERIALIZATION_ITEMS; i < OthItems.Count; )
{
    OthItems.RemoveAt(MAX_SERIALIZATION_ITEMS);
}
```

And your `ApplicationClosing` event handler should be:

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ClearUnnecessaryData();

    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppViewModel.NewsViewModel));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, ViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's a great idea =) But in order for everything to work properly "i++" must be removed.)